# How to prepare eclipse for opencl programming (Intel OpenCL SDK Installed) in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, opencl, opensuse

I installed Intel OpenCL SDK on OpenSUSE GNU/Linux 13.1. How do I prepare the Eclipse CDT IDE that comes with my distribution for OpenCL programming?

**Edit:**

After adding include path `/opt/intel/opencl-xxx/inlcude` to project and linking `/opt/intel/opencl-xxx/lib64/libOpenCL.so` to `/usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so`, Eclipse will find the `CL/cl.h` but GCC return this error:

```
Building file: ../src/HelloWorld.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.2.1.16712/include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld.d" -MT"src/HelloWorld.d" -o "src/HelloWorld.o" "../src/HelloWorld.cpp"
../src/HelloWorld.cpp:11:16: fatal error: cl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cl.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/HelloWorld.o] Error 1
```

**Edit 2:**

HelloWorld.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <CL\cl.h>

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;

cl_context CreateContext() {
    cl_int errNum;
    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_platform_id firstPlatformId;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &firstPlatformId, &numPlatforms);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS || numPlatforms <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to find any OpenCL platforms." << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    cl_context_properties contextProperties[] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)firstPlatformId,
        0
    };
    context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
                                      NULL, NULL, &errNum);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Could not create GPU context, trying CPU..." << std::endl;
        context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, NULL, NULL, &errNum);
        if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create an OpenCL GPU or CPU context." << std::endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return context;
}
cl_command_queue CreateCommandQueue(cl_context context, cl_device_id *device)
{
    cl_int errNum;
    cl_device_id *devices;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = NULL;
    size_t deviceBufferSize = -1;
    errNum = clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0, NULL, &deviceBufferSize);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "Failed call to clGetContextInfo(...,GL_CONTEXT_DEVICES,...)";
        return NULL;
    }
    if (deviceBufferSize <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "No devices available.";
        return NULL;
    }
    devices = new cl_device_id[deviceBufferSize / sizeof(cl_device_id)];
    errNum = clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, deviceBufferSize, devices,NULL);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
        delete [] devices;
        std::cerr << "Failed to get device IDs";
        return NULL;
    }
    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, NULL);
    if (commandQueue == NULL) {
        delete [] devices;
        std::cerr << "Failed to create commandQueue for device 0";
        return NULL;
    }

    *device = devices[0];
    delete [] devices;
    return commandQueue;
}

cl_program CreateProgram(cl_context context, cl_device_id device, const char* fileName)

{

    cl_int errNum;

    cl_program program;



    std::ifstream kernelFile(fileName, std::ios::in);

    if (!kernelFile.is_open())

    {

        std::cerr << "Failed to open file for reading: " << fileName << std::endl;

        return NULL;

    }



    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << kernelFile.rdbuf();



    std::string srcStdStr = oss.str();

    const char *srcStr = srcStdStr.c_str();

    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,

                                        (const char**)&srcStr,

                                        NULL, NULL);

    if (program == NULL)

    {

        std::cerr << "Failed to create CL program from source." << std::endl;

        return NULL;

    }



    errNum = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)

    {

        char buildLog[16384];

        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,

                              sizeof(buildLog), buildLog, NULL);



        std::cerr << "Error in kernel: " << std::endl;

        std::cerr << buildLog;

        clReleaseProgram(program);

        return NULL;

    }



    return program;

}

bool CreateMemObjects(cl_context context, cl_mem memObjects[3],

                      float *a, float *b)

{

    memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,

                                   sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, a, NULL);

    memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,

                                   sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, b, NULL);

    memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,

                                   sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, NULL, NULL);



    if (memObjects[0] == NULL || memObjects[1] == NULL || memObjects[2] == NULL)

    {

        std::cerr << "Error creating memory objects." << std::endl;

        return false;

    }



    return true;

}


void Cleanup(cl_context context, cl_command_queue commandQueue,

             cl_program program, cl_kernel kernel, cl_mem memObjects[3])

{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

    {

        if (memObjects[i] != 0)

            clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[i]);

    }

    if (commandQueue != 0)

        clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);



    if (kernel != 0)

        clReleaseKernel(kernel);



    if (program != 0)

        clReleaseProgram(program);



    if (context != 0)

        clReleaseContext(context);



}

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

    cl_context context = 0;

    cl_command_queue commandQueue = 0;

    cl_program program = 0;

    cl_device_id device = 0;

    cl_kernel kernel = 0;

    cl_mem memObjects[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    cl_int errNum;



    // Create an OpenCL context on first available platform

    context = CreateContext();

    if (context == NULL)

    {

        std::cerr << "Failed to create OpenCL context." << std::endl;

        return 1;

    }



    // Create a command-queue on the first device available

    // on the created context

    commandQueue = CreateCommandQueue(context, &device);

    if (commandQueue == NULL)

    {

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Create OpenCL program from HelloWorld.cl kernel source

    program = CreateProgram(context, device, "HelloWorld.cl");

    if (program == NULL)

    {

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Create OpenCL kernel

    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello_kernel", NULL);

    if (kernel == NULL)

    {

        std::cerr << "Failed to create kernel" << std::endl;

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Create memory objects that will be used as arguments to

    // kernel.  First create host memory arrays that will be

    // used to store the arguments to the kernel

    float result[ARRAY_SIZE];

    float a[ARRAY_SIZE];

    float b[ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)

    {

        a[i] = (float)i;

        b[i] = (float)(i * 2);

    }



    if (!CreateMemObjects(context, memObjects, a, b))

    {

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Set the kernel arguments (result, a, b)

    errNum = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[0]);

    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[1]);

    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[2]);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)

    {

        std::cerr << "Error setting kernel arguments." << std::endl;

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    size_t globalWorkSize[1] = { ARRAY_SIZE };

    size_t localWorkSize[1] = { 1 };



    // Queue the kernel up for execution across the array

    errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL,

                                    globalWorkSize, localWorkSize,

                                    0, NULL, NULL);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)

    {

        std::cerr << "Error queuing kernel for execution." << std::endl;

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Read the output buffer back to the Host

    errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE,

                                 0, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), result,

                                 0, NULL, NULL);

    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)

    {

        std::cerr << "Error reading result buffer." << std::endl;

        Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

        return 1;

    }



    // Output the result buffer

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)

    {

        std::cout << result[i] << " ";

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Executed program succesfully." << std::endl;

    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);



    return 0;

}
```

HelloWorld.cl :

```
__kernel void hello_kernel(
    __global const float *a,
    __global const float *b,
    __global float *result)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    result[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
}
```

Comment: Elaborate your question. What you exactly expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add one OpenCL include directory to the project and link to one libOpenCL. In my case (Ubuntu 13.04) I need to add `/opt/intel/opencl-1.xxxx/include` to the include paths of the project, which allow for the use of `#include <CL/cl.h>`.

Also add `/opt/intel/opencl-1.xxxx/lib64/` to the linker search paths and add OpenCL to the link-libraries.[image]

That should do it.

Comment: i did as you said, but still have the same problem, gcc can not find CL\cl.h, i am using Opensuse 13.1 (x64), Intel Implementation of opencl and gcc 4.8, cl.h is visible to eclipse after adding include path to project but gcc still can not find it

Comment: how does your `#include` statement look? It needs to be `#include <CL/cl.h>`. The `CL/` in the beginning is important.

Comment: it is #include<CL\cl.h>, first example of opencl programming guide book

Comment: Try `/`, not `\\`. Especially with Linux.

Comment: already tried that, exactly the same error : fatal error: CL\cl.h: No such file or directory

Comment: eclipse can see the file even when using #include<CL\cl.h> but gcc returns mentioned error

Comment: Please post your code exactly. I tried to reproduce the problem but my code compiles w/o error. Your compiler command looks fine, too, so I'm baffled right now.

Comment: Your code still contains the backslash. I pasted your exact code, copy and pasted your g++-command and got the exact same error as you did. When I changed the backslash in `CL\cl.h` to a forwardshlash  everything compiles fine. So try copy/pasting the exact include statement from my post.

Comment: posted code was the original code from book, i was using CL/cl.h, my problem was the linker include path part, now gcc will complete building and make the object file but linker returns a lot of errors about not finding openCL functions used in the code, again thanks a lot, could you please help me about the linker errors too ?

Comment: errors like this : ./src/HelloWorld.o: In function `CreateProgram(_cl_context*, _cl_device_id*, char const*)':
/home/arash/workspace/Test/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.cpp:263: undefined reference to `clCreateProgramWithSource'

Comment: I edited my answer to add a screenshot of how the linker settings are supposed to look.

Comment: That worked, sorry if my question was so simple, thank you a lot for helping me in this matter with patient. Every thing works fine to start learning opencl now :-D